# SQLite search by month

Tags: android, sqlite

I ned to search the records based on  a month but i have no success for now, with the complete date it's ok, but searching by month it's not. Here is my helper:

```
    public String getSingleTransacaoSum(String date) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    double sum = 0;

    //Cursor cursorf = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSACOES
        //  + " WHERE data = ? ", new String[] { date });

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TRANSACOES+" WHERE strftime('%m', ' DATETIME') = ?",new String[] { date });

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        sum += cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("valor"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return String.valueOf(sum);
}
```

Activity:

```
    btGetSum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                dia = (String) spinDia.getSelectedItem();
                mes = (String) spinMes.getSelectedItem();
                ano = (String) spinAno.getSelectedItem();
                String dataSendTo = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;

                dbhelper.getSingleTransacaoSum(dataSendTo);

                tvValor.setText("R$ "
                        + dbhelper.getSingleTransacaoSum(dataSendTo));

            } catch (Exception erro) {
                mensagemExibir("Erro Ao Buscar", "" + erro.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

If anyone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DATETIME is a bad name for a column, it is the name of a function.
You have to remove the column name in apostrophes strftime (...):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TRANSACOES WHERE STRFTIME('%m', column_with_datetime) = ?
```

Comment: `datetime` without parentheses is parsed as a column name.

Comment: I've changed to this: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TRANSACOES+" WHERE STRFTIME('%d',data) = ?",new String[] { date }); but, still getting value zero from query.

Comment: The parameter %d returns the day of the month, not the month.
The values ​​range from 01 to 12 and the parameter %m

Comment: I've changed this later, and yet getting zero.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be done usinga LIKE clause, IE the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TRANSACOES
WHERE DATETIME LIKE '%<month>%'
```

or in java,

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TRANSACOES+" WHERE DATETIME LIKE '%/"+monthYouWantToSearchFor+"/%'");
```

I'm assuming that `DATETIME` is the column you want to query.